# How do I autogenerate JNI Interfaces - Rust for devices (Android, iOS)

Tags: android, rust, java-native-interface

I'm trying to build a multiplatform library in Rust, I've been following this guide which seems to work fine
https://mozilla.github.io/firefox-browser-architecture/experiments/2017-09-21-rust-on-android.html

However, it's kind of a hassle to work with it cause I need to create JNI interfaces manually, like so:

```
    #[no_mangle]
    pub unsafe extern fn Java_com_mozilla_greetings_RustGreetings_greeting(env: JNIEnv, _: JClass, java_pattern: JString) -> jstring {
        let world = rust_greeting(env.get_string(java_pattern).expect("invalid pattern string").as_ptr());
        let world_ptr = CString::from_raw(world);
        let output = env.new_string(world_ptr.to_str().unwrap()).expect("Couldn't create java string!");

        output.into_inner()
    }
```

As you can see in this example I need to declare the function with the package name I'll run it in `Java_com_mozilla_greetings_RustGreetings_greeting`.

Is there any better way to build cross-platform libraries? I was also considering WebAssembly but it doesn't work weel for native Android and iOS apps.

Comment: Your library is already cross-platform; the JNI code is just there to make your library callable from Java or Kotlin. Take a look at SWIG, it can generate JNI wrappers for your Rust code, but the result will not be idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it is already cross-platform, I wouldn’t like to write JNI code in my Android (kotlin) app, looks quite ugly especially the long names, I won't be able to refactor/change directories on android, cause that will be a "breaking" change :/

Comment: Hence SWIG. It generates low-level JNI glue for you that you can put a high-level API on top of in Java/Kotlin